# The Requested resource(/myproject/Register.java) not available

Tags: java, html, servlets, web.xml

Im getting The Requested resource(/myproject/Register.java) not available error in my Myeclips  8.6.1, and mysql database, tompcat server. can any one help, these r my files

```
<html><head> <title>Register form</title></head><body>
 <form method="post" action="Register.java">
    name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
     Email id:<input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
     Password:<input type="text" name="pass"/><br/>
     <input type="submit" value="register"/> </form></body></html>
```

...........................................................
Java file. Register.java:

```
package databaseconnection;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Register extends HttpServlet{



    protected void dopost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException{

        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        String Name=request.getParameter("name");
        String Email=request.getParameter("email");
        String Password=request.getParameter("pass");


        try{

            Class.forName("com.sql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproject","root","root");
            PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into student values(?,?,?)");


            pst.setString(1,Name);
            pst.setString(2,Email);
            pst.setString(3,Password);

            int i=pst.executeUpdate();

            if(i>0){
                out.println("Your registration sucessful");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

....................................................................

web.xml

```
 <servlet>

       <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>  
       <servlet-class>Register</servlet-class>

  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>

     <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: what are you doing? please share when are you getting this error?

Comment: edit it in your post instead of comment.

Answer (score 0):

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>databaseconnection.Register</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Register.java**

```
package databaseconnection;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Register() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String Name = request.getParameter("name");
        String Email = request.getParameter("email");
        String Password = request.getParameter("pass");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproject", "root", "root");
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into student values(?,?,?)");

            pst.setString(1, Name);
            pst.setString(2, Email);
            pst.setString(3, Password);

            int i = pst.executeUpdate();
            if (i > 0) {
                out.println("Your registration sucessful");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="Register">
            name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br /> 
            Email id:<input type="text" name="email" /><br /> 
            Password:<input type="text" name="pass" /><br /> 
            <input type="submit" value="register" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: even after giving just Register instead of Register.java, still giving  same error that "Register.java"

Comment: I corrected my answer little bit..I forgot to attach package in serlvlet-class in web.xml.

Comment: is it necessary to add package name to <servlet-class> in web.xml.

Comment: i added that package name but its showing plain page, not storing values in database

Comment: You put wrong driver name.It should be com.mysql.jdbc.Driver instead of com.sql.jdbc.Driver.I put the whole working code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First the form `action` attribute value should point to the `url pattern` defined for the Servlet in web.xml.

It should be:

```
<form method="post" action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/Register">
```

*Note:* Don't forget to add the context path before servlet url name.

Second in web.xml use fully qualified name of the Servlet:

```
<servlet-class>databaseconnection.Register</servlet-class>
```

Comment: i have done what ever u said but still getting the same error

Comment: you might forget to add the error message in your post.

Comment: you mean acknowledgement message after submission ?

Comment: What error are you getting. please edit it in your post to make it clear for others.

Comment: "The Requested resource(/myproject/Register.java) not available"

Comment: don't know where are you using `Register.java`. Have you made both the changes that I told you.